# mysqldump.exe not taking full backup of mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database-backups

I have a procedure for backing up MySQL database.And also i have different MySQL servers.  This procedure works on some of MySQL servers.But on some of servers it won't works proper and create a backup file with the size of 1kb.

### Code

```
public void DatabaseBackup(string ExeLocation, string DBName)
{
    try
    {
        string tmestr = "";
        tmestr = DBName + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff") + ".sql";
        tmestr = tmestr.Replace("/", "-");
        tmestr = "c:/" + tmestr;
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(tmestr);
        ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string cmd = string.Format(@"-u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3}", "uid", "pass", "host", DBName);
        proc.FileName = ExeLocation;
        proc.RedirectStandardInput = false;
        proc.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Arguments = cmd;
        proc.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process p = Process.Start(proc);
        string res;
        res = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        file.WriteLine(res);
        p.WaitForExit();
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Can any one tell me what is the problem and how can i solve it.

Comment: what does the exception say?

Comment: There is no any exception.It creates the backup file with no data.And the size of file is 1 kb.

Comment: Are you sure? your catching some but never doing anything with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the answer.
We need SELECT and LOCK_TABLE privilege on MySQL user or database on which we want backup.
After setting these privilege on database i am able to take full backup of that database.

Comment: still it is not giving all data

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Backup Statement?

Here is the best way to backup your database :

```
private void BackupDatabase()
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
            string savePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Backups\"+time+"_"+saveFileDialogBackUp.FileName;
            if (saveFileDialogBackUp.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try {
                        using (Process mySqlDump = new Process())
                        {
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.FileName = @"mysqldump.exe";
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-u" + user + " -p" + pwd + " -h" + server + " " + database + " -r \"" + savePath + "\"";
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
                            mySqlDump.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                            mySqlDump.Start();
                            mySqlDump.WaitForExit();
                            mySqlDump.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Connot backup database! \n\n" + ex);
                    }
                MessageBox.Show("Done! database backuped!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Still same problem is there it works on some servers and won't work on some of the MySQL server.It creates a sql file with some commented lines and nothing.Is there any problem with configuration of MySQL server.

Comment: Finally i got the answer. We need SELECT and LOCK_TABLE privilege on MySQL user or database on which we want backup. After setting these privilege on database i am able to take full backup of that database.